# On data granularity involving PCA

Tags: pca, dataset, frequency

So I have a very large amount of data, on a 15 minute frequency. I want to reduce dimensionality, so PCA seems like a good choice. However, there's a catch -- I will use monthly data, not 15 minutes. Therefore, I need to convert high frequency data to low frequency. The question is if it makes more sense to do PCA before or after conversion.

I believe converting to monthly data first and then applying PCA sounds much better, because this way I conserve PCA's properties (projections are uncorrelated). On the other hand, if I do PCA and then convert to monthly, the resulting series are significantly correlated.

My advisor believes we might lose information present in the high frequency data if we convert to monthly before doing PCA. I think such information will be lost either way.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpreting something but the "uncorrelateness of PCA" you seem to refer at, refers at the relation between the projected PCA scores with each other (the property in question is actually "orthogonality"). The projections along the axis defined by a particular principal mode of variation (ie. the score) can be significantly correlated if the original data share some relation along that particular mode of variation. Your advisor is on the right here I think. The bigger question is *why* you use PCA to begin with.

Comment: @usεr11852 well, if PCA is done over a set of zero mean variables then the projections should always be uncorrelated, right? From my understanding, that's a consequence of orthogonality.
As for why I'm using PCA, it is simply to reduce the dimensionality of the dataset, since I'm dealing with 50+ variables and it might be a little too costly to use them all in our models.

Comment: Errmm... sort of! :D Orthogonality does not guarantee zero correlation (eg. check Rodgers et al. [Linearly Independent, Orthogonal, and Uncorrelated Variables](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~bmomen/BIOM621/LineardepCorrOrthogonal.pdf) for some counterexamples) but this is somewhat immaterial to your question. You say you want to do reduce dimensionality but it is unclear why you want to do this so it is unclear why your advisor's very reasonable suggestion is potentially suboptimal.

Comment: You did not describe your data well, I think. How does it look? Is your analysis time series analysis?

Comment: Yes, it is time series analysis. More specifically, the data is load demand from certain points. We cannot model all load points together since they are too many, so we want to generate a smaller number of variables that are a good representation of all load points.

Comment: @usεr11852 I'm confused. Doesn't that article show exactly that, if X and Y have zero mean, orthogonality and uncorrelation are the same?

Comment: Yes, it does, sorry I misread your comment at time, I thought you demeaned after PCA; a convenient table can be found [here](https://alecospapadopoulos.wordpress.com/2014/08/16/orthogonality-and-correlation/). As mentioned though this is somewhat immaterial to your question. So going back to your question can you please describe your data in terms of dimensions?

Comment: @usεr11852 It's electric power demand data (MW) on a 15 min frequency for a couple years. So around 50 thousand obsevations, and 44 load points, meaning 44 variables.

Comment: OK! So you are having 44 time-series of ~50k points each, splendid. What you trying to do with these? (Note:The dataset this size should not a problem for most modern algorithms.)

Comment: As I said, the main objective is dimensionality reduction. We intend to simulate these series on a monthly level, 1 to 3 years ahead, probably through a state space model. However, to avoid dealing with a 44 dimensional multivariate model, we want to obtain uncorrelated signals through PCA and model them univariately. I know 44 dim modeling is possible but we will probably deal with 200+ in the future. Then, we get back to the original series through a technique that would be lengthy to explain and not the point of the question. Should we do PCA before or after converting the data to monthly?